# How to make typescript infer a more specific type of a class property?

Tags: typescript

I have an class with a property that is meant to be extensible by a developer, but I am having trouble making typescript infer (or make the developer be able to specify) the more specific type. In this example I have a property "models" on my application class that should be compatible with the type "Models". In my case, it will be overriden with a more specific type (almost) 100% of the time by the developer and never modified once set - and will be set before consumed.

How can I help typescript understand the more specific type - or allowing the developer to overriding the type? Keep in mind this applies to many more properties which makes it inconvenient to specify the type using "const app = new App({ config, models, stats, state });"

```
// External modules/types
interface Model {
  id: number;
}
interface UserModel extends Model {
  name: string;
}
interface Models {
  [service: string]: Model;
}
class Application {
  public models: Models = {};
}

// My app
const app = new Application();
app.models = {
  User: {
    id: 1,
      name: 'Kent',
  } as UserModel,
};

// app.models does not have .User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript does type inference (of the kind that you want to happen) only when there is some generic type parameter that can be inferred. Also, to make it happen, you typically should have a function which takes generic parameter, then its type could be inferred from specific type of actual argument that you pass to a function.

In your case, you could make `Application` class generic, and pass `models` as parameter to a constructor. In this case, it's even not necessary to have explicit interface for `Models` - the constraint is specified inline in the `Application` generic class declaration:

```
// External modules/types
interface Model {
  id: number;
}
interface UserModel extends Model {
  name: string;
}

class Application<ServiceNames extends string, 
              Models extends { [service in ServiceNames]: Model }> {
  constructor(models: Models) {
    this.models = models;
  }
  public models: Models;
}

// My app
const app = new Application( {
  User: {
    id: 1,
      name: 'Kent',
  } as UserModel,
});

let n = app.models.User.name; // inferred as string
```

Comment: This helped me so much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
interface Model {
  id: number;
}

interface UserModel extends Model {
  name: string;
}

interface Models<T extends Model> {
  [service: string]: T;
}

class Application<T extends Model> {
  public models: Models<T> = {};
}

const app = new Application<UserModel>();

app.models = {
  User: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Kent',
  }
}
```